# opening google map fragment on button click in android studio

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, google-maps-api-2, buttonclick, mapfragment

I would like to create an app in Android Studio that has a Button in Main Activity and when i clicks this button, it should open a google map with my customized lat,lng markers and camera functions as an another activity. I tried this one by creating a Button in the Main Activity.XML and wrote buttonOnClickListener() by specifying Intent that MainActivity.this,Mapfragment.class.For this I selected GoogleMaps as my start Activity instead of blank activity at starting of my project. And also for this MapFragment, I got Google maps API key. But when I run this App on my android mobile, it simply opening google map with my customized lat,lng instead of showing my Main Activity which is having a Button in it. I am confused with this, can anyone help me out of this problem.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got it. I tried to solve this problem and got a solution for it. Initially as I said, at the starting of my project I selected a google map activity instead of blank activity. So now, to get a Button in my Main activity, I have created a MainActivity.XML in Layout folder and added a Button to it. Then, for this MainActivity.XML file corresponding .Java class was created and specified the MainActivity.XML in it and declared the Button and wrote OnClickListener for Button, so that when the Button clicks it should open my google map fragment with customized location. Importantly, we should specify this mainactivity.java in the Manifest.XML as an Activity specifying it as a Launcher activity in the Application. Now, run the app and first it displays MainActivity with a Button and now when I clicks it, it opens my google map fragment activity with the help of Intent.